# Use more android menu items in one row

Tags: android, android-menu

I'm trying to use 6 **android menu** items in one row,but by default only 3 items are Passable.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No (unless you use a split action bar). From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html):

> - Action buttons in the main action bar may not occupy more than 50% of the bar's width. Action buttons on bottom action bars can use the
>     entire width.
> - The screen width in density-independent pixels (dp) determine the number of items that will fit in the main action bar:
>
>   - smaller than 360 dp = 2 icons
>   - 360-499 dp = 3 icons
>   - 500-599 dp = 4 icons
>   - 600 dp and larger = 5 icons

Comment: Also worth noting that if the limit were 3 and you add 4 (or more) options then only 2 would be visible as the last spot would be used by the "more" ellipsis (...) to open the drop down containing the items that don't fit.

Comment: I know but i'd like set all items in one row